# Docker VS VM when scaling

Tags: virtual-machine, docker

I have an basic understanding of Docker and VM - trying to wrap my head around why.

Assume I have a standard web app. It consists of NGINX, PHP-FPM and MySQL all running localhost. As the site begins to grow, the DB becomes more taxed and competes for resources with PHP and NGINX - along with other services.

I move the MySQL to a dedicated host - problem solved - for now.

Eventually I move each "service" into a distinct EC2 instance (Google compute, etc) and link them together. Now I have a truly distributed system. To address scale, I would implement proxies in-front of appropriate services and further distribute my infrastructure.

Why would I use Docker on the VM's -- or would I? Would a single VM contain multiple NGINX instance? One cache-proxy, one load-balancing-proxy, X number NGINX instances that communicate with PHP-FPM (possibly running on distinct EC2 instances?).

Regards,
ALex

Comment: Isn't Docker for virtualizing apps? Eg. bring only the app to your computer, instead of a whole desktop? I think these are 2 completely different products and can't be compared. Its pointless to use these in a VM server environment, especially since a VM by itself is portable. You can move the VM to a different server quite painlessly, so Docker is not needed at all.

Comment: Good question - as I understand it docker allows you to container-ize services at a fraction of the overhead of a full VM.

So I guess - in the case above - I might have 3 or 4 NGINX instances listening to different ports but running under the same core OS but distinct and secure as if they were a separate VM. Not sure if that makes sense from a performance standpoint. Can a single VM handle more traffic when two distinct NGINX process or would one handle more?

Comment: The thing is, you can put things in boxes, but if these boxes are still all in the same room, the room will be full quickly. But if you use different rooms of the house, and store boxes in different rooms, then obviously the box can be bigger. AKA: you are limited by what your system can handle. If you have 100 VM's all on the same machine, they still impact eachother as if all processes were in just one VM. The same applies with Docker. You still use the HOST CPU and memory. And if you run out,... performance issues.

Comment: The only difference is that with a VM, you add an OS layer that takes performance too, where you aren't with Docker. But if you use docker inside a VM, thats just pointless. And if you are to use Docker, then the use of a VM is pointless by itself.